# How does QGIS Identify Features plugin work i.e. what is logic behind it?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, identify

I'm new to QGIS and python as well.

I need attributes and their values of a selected vector layer, in the similar manner as Identify Feature works only difference is I don't wish to show them in a dialog box.

For a better approach I went through Cookbook and few of posts on GIS and have tried function like getFeatures() but no success.

Answer (score 1):

if `rect` is a `Qgsrectangle` centered in the point clicked on canvas, then the code is synthetically

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest(rect)
for feat in layer.getFeatures(request):
    <yout code> of the QgsFeature "feat"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def changeValue(self,point,button):
    request = QgsFeatureRequest()
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(request))
    self.dlg.show()
```

Above function resulted to the string below in lineEdit

Comment: Luigi's answer is correct. Follow that.

Comment: @NathanW First of all thnkx for answering now following Luigi's answer when I tried the code I've posted above this string appeared in the code below 
<qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest object at 0X048E2DB0>

Comment: That is because you are not mean to use it like that. Do exactly what Luigi posted.